# Populating a recursive TreeView list

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, treeview, ms-access-2007

If I have a Microsoft Access database populated like this:

[image: db data]

Using ASP VBScript, how would I print that into a treeview list? With infinite potential levels, as any page can have child pages...

For example, the above db should print to look like this:

[image: List]

---

Update:

I am now stuck on the recursion aspect of this...

```
...

rs.open "SELECT id,parent_id,page_name,node_path FROM pages ORDER BY node_path",conn
records = rs.GetRows

...

<%
    function tree(parent, arrPages)

        children = false

        for x = 0 to ubound(arrPages, 2)
            if (cint(arrPages(1, x)) = parent) then
                if (children = false AND parent > 0) then 
                    children = true
                    Response.Write("<ul>")
                end if
            %>
            <li>
                <%=arrPages(2,x)%>
                <% Call Tree(arrPages(0,x), arrPages) %>
            </li>
            <%
            end if
        next

        if (children = true AND parent > 0) then 
            %></ul><%
        end if

    end function

    Response.Write "<ul>"
    Call tree(0, records)
    Response.Write "</ul>"
%>
```

However, this only writes:

[image]

Comment: I would read the entries in one go using [GetRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx) - far easier. From there you can loop through the record set as much as you like.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, GetRows is definitely the way to go. However I can't quite figure out the recursion aspect of this now...

Comment: `node-path` for part-time should be `.0.1.3.6.` and for `employees` it should be `.0.1.`

Answer (score 0):

I put your data into an array and your code worked perfectly.

Are you sure your query is pulling out the correct data?

```
<%
Dim records(3, 6)

records(0, 0) = 1
records(1, 0) = 0
records(3, 0) = ".0."
records(2, 0) = "Home"

records(0, 1) = 2
records(1, 1) = 1
records(3, 1) = ".0.1."
records(2, 1) = "About"

records(0, 2) = 3
records(1, 2) = 1
records(3, 2) = ".0.1."
records(2, 2) = "Contact"

records(0, 3) = 4
records(1, 3) = 2
records(3, 3) = ".0.1.2."
records(2, 3) = "What we do"

records(0, 4) = 5
records(1, 4) = 3
records(3, 4) = ".0.1.3."
records(2, 4) = "Employees"

records(0, 5) = 6
records(1, 5) = 5
records(3, 5) = ".0.1.3.5."
records(2, 5) = "Full time"

records(0, 6) = 7
records(1, 6) = 5
records(3, 6) = ".0.1.3.5."
records(2, 6) = "Part time"

    function tree(parent, arrPages)

        children = false

        for x = 0 to ubound(arrPages, 2)
            if (cint(arrPages(1, x)) = parent) then
                if (children = false AND parent > 0) then 
                    children = true
                    Response.Write("<ul>")
                end if
            %>
            <li>
                <%=arrPages(2,x)%>
                <% Call Tree(arrPages(0,x), arrPages) %>
            </li>
            <%
            end if
        next

        if (children = true AND parent > 0) then 
            %></ul><%
        end if

    end function

    Response.Write "<ul>"
    Call tree(0, records)
    Response.Write "</ul>"
%>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: His SQL is "SELECT id,parent_id,page_name,node_path" where yours seems to be in the order id, parent_id, node_path, page_name

Comment: No, mine is same as yours: id, parent_id, page_name, node_path. Are all results being returned by your query? Have you tried Response.Write all of the value sin the array to check?

Comment: Sorry @pee2pee, just realised you weren't the OP, so you can ignore those questions :)

Comment: hey @john, thanks for the input, I started comparing why yours works and mine doesn't and it turns out I had to remove Option Explicit from the top of my page... thanks